# jQuery has no method 'toLowerCase' error. ajs.js and mediaelement conflicting

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm having some conflicts within some code I just picked up to work with. It has the library AJS js loaded up and it is being used and I am trying to load up and use jQuery along with the mediaelement html5 video player.  I can load everything together and use jQuery and use $ as long as I $.noConflict() before my document ready.  However when I try to use the mediaelement resource and actually create my video player I am getting this error.

I am initalizing the mediaelement player like so :

```
videoplayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {
        poster: 'http://dev.billiondollarbrows.com/images/poster.jpg'
})
```

And this is the error that is being thrown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return a.nodeName.toLowerCase()} has no method 'toLowerCase'
f.extend.acceptDatajquery.min.js:2
f.extend.datajquery.min.js:2
f.extend._datajquery.min.js:2
f.event.triggerjquery.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.triggerjquery.min.js:3
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.triggerjquery.min.js:3
mejs.MediaElementPlayer.meReadymediaelement-and-player.js:2001
jQuery.extend.successmediaelement-and-player.js:1700
mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.updateNativemediaelement-and-player.js:1256
mejs.HtmlMediaElementShim.createmediaelement-and-player.js:833
mejs.MediaElementmediaelement-and-player.js:788
mejs.MediaElementPlayer.initmediaelement-and-player.js:1831
mejs.MediaElementPlayermediaelement-and-player.js:1681
(anonymous function)before-after.js:3
f.Callbacks.njquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.min.js:2
e.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.Bjquery.min.js:2
```

CLOSED: Solved this problem by using video.js player instead.  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there is an element with the ID of `player` in the DOM?

Comment: There is definitely an element with the ID of `player` in the DOM.  Here it is : `<video id='player' width="704" height="440" controls="controls" preload="none" autoplay="true">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library in particular, but that error suggests that the variable 'a' has no nodeName property - are you sure you're passing a DOM element to that function (or it's getting passed internally)?

Comment: I also looked for any element in the DOM with a name/id of node or nodeName and came up with nothing... I may just switch libs to video.js and see if that works with this existing codebase

Comment: @user834418 `nodeName` is a property that DOM element objects have, it stores the type of HTML tag the element is, e.g. "A", or "IMG".

Comment: yeah, I have read that if you have a DOM element with a name/id of `nodeName` it can cause errors with jQuery, so I was just saying that is not the problem

Comment: The `a` variable is not relevant. `Object function(a) {} has no method "toLowerCase"` suggests somehow a function got passed to where a string was expected and blew up when the code tried to lowercase that should-be string.